# Prove $Ax = \frac{1}{2}x$ only has the trivial solution where $A$ has all integer entries.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Prove $Ax = \frac{1}{2}x$ only has the trivial solution where $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix with integer entries and $x = (x_1, \ldots , x_n)$.

I am a bit rusty on my linear algebra and trying to review. I tried using the Invertible Matrix theorem. The problem was I couldn't seem to gain any traction with any of the equivalent statements.

Here is the link for anyone that needs a refresher: [Invertible Matrix Theorem](https://www.math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m22f06/public_html/imt.pdf)

```
Looking for hints rather than a specific solution.
```

Comment: It means that $\frac12$ is an eigenvalue: a root of the characteristic equation.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: It means that $\frac12$ _is not_ an eigenvalue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The eigenvalues of $A$ are the roots of its characteristic polynomial, which is a monic polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: I am probably missing something, but it seems to me that any matrix with no $1/2$ eigenvalue has only $x=0$ as the (trivial) solution.

Comment: @jobe Of course, but how do you know that $\frac12$ is *not* an eigenvalue?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos By Gauss Lemma a monic polynomial with integer coefficients only has integer or irrational roots thus $\frac{1}{2}$ cannot be a root thus there is no non-zero solution to $Ax = \frac{1}{2}x$

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: I misunderstood the question... I thought that what was being asked is to prove that $Ax=\frac{1}{2}x$ has $x=0$ its only solution **when** $A$ has integer entries, what is obviously wrong. Now I see that $A$ having integer entries is **assumed**, not something to be proved.

Comment: @jobe The problem could be reworded to be made clearer. Your interpretation would be right if we added another word: "... **only** when $A$ has all integer entries."

Comment: @jobe I edited the question phrasing; hopefully it doesn't cause confusion for future readers now.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Evaluate the characteristic polynomial of $A$ at $\lambda=\frac12$. Since all coefficients are integers and the leading term is $\lambda^n$, what can you say about the value?

Comment: I take it this was headed in the same direction as the other answer using the Rational Root Theorem. We would need $2 \lvert \lambda^n = \frac{1}{2^n}$ and clearly this is not possible.

Comment: @all.over: The Rational Root Theorem will do it, yes. I never recall how it goes, though, so what I really had in mind was that the first term is the single term that is not a multiple of $2^{-(n-1)}$.

Answer (score 3):

Write it as $x=2Ax$. If this has a nonzero solution, it has a nonzero rational solution and indeed a nonzero integer solution. But if $x$ has integer entries,
$x=2Ax$ has even entries. So then $x=2Ax$ has entries divisible by $4$, etc.....

Comment: I'm sort of following this solution. Not quite sure what the divisibility by 4 does for it though.

Comment: Well, then $x=2Ax$ will have entries divisible by $8$, etc.

Comment: It seems there is something obvious I am missing here. $A$ has integer entries so $2A$ has even entries. If $x$ has integer entries then $2Ax$ has even integer entries (even if x=0) thus $x$ has even entries by $x = 2Ax = A2x$ so we can divide  entries of $x$ by $4$ but then similar reasoning we can divide entries of $x$ by $8$, ..., $2^n$. Hence entries of $x$ are of the form $2^nk_i, 1\le i \le n, k_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ where $n$ grows indefinitely thus an absurdity that isn't possible unless $x = (0,0, \ldots, 0)$.